# efficiently get single pixels from large images in aws lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, image-processing, aws-lambda

i would like to implement a lambda in aws which receives as input pixel coordinates (x/y), retrieve that pixel's RGB from one image, and then do something with it.
the catch now is that the image is very large: 21600x10800 pixels (a 684MB tif file).
Many of the image's pixels will likely never be accessed (its a world map so it includes e.g. oceans, for which no lambda calls will happen. But i don't know which pixels will be needed.)
The result of the lambda will be persisted so that the image operation is only done once per pixel.

My main concern is that i would like to avoid large unnecessary processing time and costs. I expect multiple calls per second of the lambda. The naive way would be to throw the image into an s3 bucket, then read it in the lambda to get one pixel - but i would think that then each lambda invoke would become very heavy. I could do some custom solution such as storing the rows separately but was wondering if there is some set of technologies that handles it more elegant.
Right now i am using Node.js 14.x but that's not a strong requirement.
the image is in tif format but i could convert it to another image format beforehand if needed. (just not to the answer of the lambda as that is even bigger)

How can i efficiently design this lambda?

Comment: How do you want to upload 600MB image to lambda, if not through S3?

Comment: You really need to split / tile that image up into a few thousand smaller images, each maybe 100x100 px large, and then calculate based on the request pixel which subimage you actually want to access. at that point the file should only be a few kb large and should be easily loadable and readable from within the lambda in a few ms. Depending on what you actually want to achieve in the end it may not be necessary for the lambda to exist at all if the caller could retrieve the small image themselves and extract the information just as easily.

Comment: Why do you want to use a Lambda? The requirement of "multiple calls per second" would be enough to make me look at other technology. And once you make that step, you have multiple options for dealing with your file.

Comment: A couple of thoughts... 1) Your TIFF file size implies it is uncompressed - you could consider using lossless LZW compression for example. 2) As 71% of the Earth's surface is water, you could presumably make all the water pixels black meaning they would compress really well, which would aid your file size considerably.

Comment: the reason for a lambda was ease-of-use mostly - but yes i might check still also consider other technologies.

Comment: @luk2302 - if you phrase it into an answer i think i can accept it (based on my tests below)
Regarding LZW: Thats quite neat! Although i think even after compression there would still be a lot of data though
Yeah reading only some bytes into TIFF was what i had in mind - for the moment i will settle with the sub-images but could still be an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the useful information!
so after some testing i settled for the solution from luk2302's comment with 100x100 pixel sub-images hosted on s3, but can't flag a comment as the solution. My tests showed that the lambda operates within 110ms to access a pixel (from the now only 4kb large files) which i think is quite sufficient for my expectations. (the very first request was at 1s time, but now even requests to sub-images which have never been touched before are answered within 110ms)

Parsifal's solution is what i originally envisioned to be ideal in order to really only check the relevant data (open question then being which image library actually omits loading the entire file) but i don't have the means to check the file system aspect more closely if that has more potential. In my case indeed the requests are very much burst driven (with long periods of expected inactivity after the bursts), so for the moment i will remain with a lambda but will keep the mentioned alternatives in mind.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, I think Lambda is the wrong solution unless your traffic is very bursty. If you have continuous traffic with "multiple calls per second," it will be more cost-effective to use an alternate technology, such as EC2 or ECS. And these give you far more control over storage.

However, if you're set on using Lambda, then I think the best solution is to store the file on an [EFS volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/whatisefs.html), then [mount that filesystem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-filesystem.html) onto your Lambda. In my experiments, it takes roughly 150 ms for a Lambda to read an arbitrary byte from a file on EFS, using Python and the `mmap` package.

Of course, if your TIFF library attempts to read the file into memory before performing any operations, this is moot. The TIFF format is designed so that shouldn't be necessary, but some libraries take the easy way out (because in most cases you're displaying or transforming the entire image). You may need to pre-process your file, to produce a raw byte format, in order to be able to make single-pixel gets.